# Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine"

Tags: gnome, gtk

I have downloaded and installed a new theme before in my fedora machine.

However, I got this warning when I load gvim, nautilus every time.

```
(gvim:4629): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",
(gvim:4629): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "equinox",
```

How can I download this theme engine?? and remove this warning?

Answer (score 11):

On Ubuntu 13.10 the command i needed was:

```
sudo apt-get install gtk2-engines-murrine:i386
```

I know the question is about fedora but I ended up here where one of the answers pointed me in the right direction.

Just in case it would be helpful to others.

Comment: works on 64 bit too

Answer (score 9):

Install gtk-engines package from your distro's repository. If there's not a gtk-engines package, search for a package with a similar name, you shall find one.

For ubuntu the package name is gtk2-engines. You may need to reinstall the package:

```
$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall gtk2-engines
```

Comment: I am using fedora, how can i Download that from distro? I am a linux new bie :(

Comment: AFAIR, Fedora uses Yum to get packages, if so, try running "yum install gtk-engines" from your terminal.

Comment: Alternatively, try downloading an rpm package for your architecture from here: http://fr2.rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=gtk-engines
and install it using "rpm -i <package-name>".

Comment: i reinstalled (with the mentioned command), and the error repeated. 
(i'm actually trying to run a Qt4 on Mint 17)

Answer (score 9):

If it's unable to find the engine, it means you haven't installed them yet. Simply do someting like this:

```
sudo yum install gtk2-engines gtk-murrine-engine gtk-equinox-engine
```

Comment: this is a correcter answer as the other one doesn't say anything about the murrine or equinox engine

Comment: Packages are named `gtk2-engines-murrine` and `gtk2-engines-equinox` for some distributions.

Comment: it is "gtk2-engines-murrine" in ubuntu. Perhaps you should also consider installing "murrine-themes"

Answer (score 8):

People experiencing this problem with, eg Acrobat Reader on 64bit installs should try this:

> sudo apt-get install gkt2-murrine-engine:i386

Comment: could u elaborate Usage of gkt2murrine engine?

Comment: I've no idea what it does under the hood, just that Acrobat Reader complains if it's missing, and doesn't if it's present. There are accounts of problems with older versions of vmware-player requiring gtk2-murrine-engine as well.

Comment: I think the key for me was `gtk2-engines-murrine:i386` and `gtk2-engines:i386` . Ubuntu 18.04 running Acrobat Reader 9.5.5 so fillable PDFs work.

Answer (score 2):

If none of the other answers solved your problem, you can also try

```
sudo apt-get install libgtkmm-2.4-1c2a libgtkmm-2.4-dev
```

This worked for me (Ubuntu 14.04 x64, Gnome 3.12). I already had the gtk2-engines-murrine installed (both i386 and x64), and changing the GTK_MODULES didn't do anything for me.

Comment: Thank you. I had the exact same problem and this solution worked like charm

Answer (score 1):

I installed `sudo apt-get install libgtkmm-2.4-1c2a libgtkmm-2.4-dev`
But gives that error again.Then I download [murrine-0.90.3.tar.gz](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB0QFjAAahUKEwiq-vKn8JnJAhWCBI4KHY39Anw&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdownload.gnome.org%2Fsources%2Fmurrine%2F0.90%2Fmurrine-0.90.3.tar.gz.meta4&usg=AFQjCNHAHhVWSuEX__ABxpAkO705NSXeAw&sig2=ikxpuuONLCIvd4FDgXBKIg) and

```
tar -xvf murrine-0.90.3.tar.gz
cd murrine-0.90.3
./configure
make
make install
```

now works. no errors.hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

How about installing package `gnome-themes-standard`. 
Try `sudo apt-get install gnome-themes-standard` or similar command in the corresponding way depending on what linux package management used.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:  Using Synaptic, search for 'gnome-themes' 
As a side-effect that will *also* list an entry **gtk2-engines** 
So just install gtk2-engines, i.e. `Mark for installation` and `Apply`

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu 20.04, it is `sudo apt-get install murrine-themes` to solve the warning.

Answer (score 0):

The following command is what I needed to solve this problem on Arch Linux.

```
sudo pacman -S gtk-engine-murrine
```